# GAN Discriminator denies generated models

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, generator, discriminator

I have GAN network which should generates 3d models of swords. I built it bases on Tensorflow GAN Tutorial of generating digit images: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/generative/dcgan .

I am converting .obj files (all models have 240 faces) into mat `[240;9]` (where 9 is the coordinates of the vertices of the face).
All coords <= 1.0 and I have ~ 3000+ models in dataset.

I mixed my 3d models matrixes and started to learn my GAN network. Every 100 epoch I prints the average of the discriminator prediction for: dataset which used to learn, dataset of unused models for checking discriminator, generated models and garbage (random generated matrixes `[240,9]`)

Discriminator function of activation is linear: if result is > 0 => discriminator accepted model, if it is < 0 mean discriminator denied model.

But what I have in result:

```
> 1-th epoch:
> Learned Dataset AVG Prediction: ~ 0.002
> Unused Checking Dataset AVG Prediction ~ 0.0018
> Generated Dataset AVG Prediction ~ -0.002
> Garbage Dataset AVG Prediction ~ -1.5
> 
> 6000-th epoch:
> Learned Dataset AVG Prediction: ~ 17.000
> Unused Checking Dataset AVG Prediction ~ 19.000
> Generated Dataset AVG Prediction ~ -3.000
> Garbage Dataset AVG Prediction ~ -20000.000
```

It is mean that discriminator learns right, but generator can't deceive a discriminator. And I got 3D model like a sword, but where polygons rotated randomly and haven't connections: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kHjur.jpg (100.000 epoch)

Am I right what my dataset is good, and discriminator learns correctly?
Should I change structure of Generator Model Network?
What could be the reason for such training?

```
def make_generator_model():
    model = tf.keras.Sequential()
    model.add(layers.Dense(30 * 9 * 512, use_bias=False, input_shape=(100,)))
    model.add(layers.BatchNormalization())
    model.add(layers.LeakyReLU())

    model.add(layers.Reshape((30, 9, 512)))
    assert model.output_shape == (None, 30, 9, 512)  # Note: None is the batch size

    model.add(layers.Conv2DTranspose(128, (5, 5), strides=(2, 1), padding='same', use_bias=False))
    assert model.output_shape == (None, 60, 9, 128)
    model.add(layers.BatchNormalization())
    model.add(layers.LeakyReLU())

    model.add(layers.Conv2DTranspose(64, (5, 5), strides=(2, 1), padding='same', use_bias=False))
    assert model.output_shape == (None, 120, 9, 64)
    model.add(layers.BatchNormalization())
    model.add(layers.LeakyReLU())

    model.add(layers.Conv2DTranspose(1, (5, 5), strides=(2, 1), padding='same', use_bias=False, activation='tanh'))
    assert model.output_shape == (None, 240, 9, 1)

    return model
```

All other code from my program is identical to the code from the TensorFlow site

Answer (score 0):

In a case like this, there are many reasons why it could be hard for the generator to produce good outputs. The first thing that came to my mind is the representation you used. Let's assume there are no holes in your 3D models, this means joint vertices of neighboring faces have to exactly match. 
This is very hard to achieve since your outputs are floats and so there are probably going to be a lot of small slits or overlaps between the faces, features you probably wont find in your original dataset. This makes it quite easy for your discriminator to distinguish the generated samples. (Almost every vertex appears more than once -> original sample, very small difference between vertex positions -> generated sample)

One solution to this problem could be to change your representation, like one of the following options:

1. represent each face with its center point, for creating the 3D model you simply connect each point with its three closest neighbors.
2. save each vertex individually and reconstruct the surfaces later by connecting each vertex with its three closest neighbors.

Option 1) has the additional advantage of further reducing your input space, but might lead to slightly different results. There are some edge-case surfaces that cannot be represented as described above, but these are the most simple approaches. If you have complicated 3D models that cannot be represented like this, you have to come up with something else, but there are a lot of options to choose from.

Comment: I did not store 3d models in such structures, fearing a false merger during model recovery. Well, apparently, the main direction you suggested correctly, I need to come up with how to store 3d model to then successfully deploy it. The question then is the following, in theory, such a storage structure 3d model will work with a huge number of iterations, or not a fact, I need to experiment with the layers of the generator? And so far I will go look for information about how to store the 3d model.

Translated with www.DeepL.com/Translator (free version)

Comment: Yes, you might need to experiment with the architecture of the model further  down the line, but for now I would suggest to focus on the issue at hand (representation of the 3d models). I see why you hesitated using one of the suggested methods, but i would advise to first try one of those before thinking about something more complex. Implementing these simple approaches should be rather quickly and then you can decide whether or not you need a more complicated approach.

Comment: Another idea i just had:

instead of changing the representation you could adapt your loss function. Calculating the center of a face is a differentiable function and so you could leave your representation and your model as they are, but compute the loss as a function of the centers instead of a function of the vertices. 

old: `loss = mse(y_true-y_pred)`
new: `loss = mse(compute_centers(y_true)-compute_centers(y_pred))`

Make sure to only use methods that tf can differentiate when writing the compute_centers method. 
Keep me updated, sounds like an interesting project ;)

Comment: I think, my loss calculating really bad for my way to saving model in mat. I will try to calc loss using poly centres, but i suppose it's not enough to get right rotation. I'm gonna try and figure out how to add surface rotation to the loss. For example, I can think of something with a normal of surface. I tried 2 simple ways, but in all ways if I have 4 far-reaching points, it will join together to form a pyramid. I can solve it like geometry task, but first of all I need to know how to work with ML.